# c++ regex match beginning of line

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string that looks like this

```
text here++ text
+ text text
+ text
text text
```

I want to replace + with - but only at the the beginning of the lines so that it looks like this:

```
text here++ text
- text text
- text
text text
```

I'm trying a regex like this:

```
string text = "the-above-text";
regex reg("^\\++.*$");
text = regex_replace(text, reg, "-");
```

but this ^ matches the beginning of the text, not the beginning of the line.

I've been googling for hours and it seems there's no way to make the engine to work in multi line mode.

Is there a way I can do this? Or any newer c++ standard that supports multi-line ^ and $? I'm using g++

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex for this? It's a trivial piece of string manipulation.

Comment: Use `regex reg("(?:^|\n)\++.*$")`. There is no multiline mode in C++ regex.

Comment: @NeilButterworth in reality it's much more complex than that, I just simplified the example for clarity :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it says unknown escape sequence. I replaced \++ with \\++ but now it doesn't replace anything :)

Comment: @LachoTomov I copied it from your post, please format it correctly. It must be `regex reg("(?:^|\n)\\++.*$")`. And post a real life example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Did you mean `"(?:^|\\n)\\++.*$"` or with Raw string: `R"((?:^|\n)\++.*$)"`

Comment: unfortunately none of these work :D but i just figured out a good way - just split the string by \n and then regex replace each line separately - this way there is no need to deal with ^ and $

Comment: @Jarod42 There is no difference between `"\\n"` or `"\n"`. Both LF and `\n` match a newline symbol in regex.

Comment: Lacho, please add your code to the question, it is off-topic now.

Comment: pfff weird people live around here :D I added 2 more lines of code, hope that makes them happy :)

Comment: So, you want to replace the whole line? Or only the 1+ `+` symbols at the line start? If the latter, use https://ideone.com/leKxL3

Comment: What if there are multiple `+`s? Do you still want only one `-`?

Comment: @xskxzr I'm only interested in the syntax for matching the beginning of the line, the rest is easy :)

Comment: Then why do you say my suggestion did not work? `(?:^|\n)` matches either start of string or a newline.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes this syntax `(^|\n)` seems to do the trick, thanks!

Comment: @LachoTomov That's not that easy... I think you have to use a loop instead of a one-line `regex_replace`.

Comment: @xskxzr yeah seems like this will be the cleanest solution. Maybe not the fastest but i can live with it.

Comment: thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match either end of line or start of string, use a `(^|\n)` alternation group.

To replace a streak of 1+ `+` chars at the start of each line with a single `-` (hyphen) use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    std::string s = "text here++ text\n+ text text\n+ text\ntext text";
    std::regex r("(^|\n)\\++");
    std::cout << std::regex_replace(s, r, "$1-") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/leKxL3).

Note that to re-insert the newline symbol back into the result, the `$1` placeholder that refers to Group 1 value is used in the replacement pattern (else, it will get removed).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    std::string text =
        "text here++ text\n" \
        "+ text text++\n"\
        "+ text++\n" \
        "text text";

    std::string result;
    std::regex re("(?:^|\n)\\++");
    result = std::regex_replace(text, re, "\n-");

    std::cout <<result << std::endl;
}
```

[can be seen running here](https://ideone.com/1474yh#stdin)

Comment: You add an extra newline at the beginning of the string. I don't know why ideone.com does not show this newline.

Comment: @xskxzr: input string doesn't begin with `+`, so `^` is not replaced in the example. but indeed it would be problematic for other input.